# Remove space in the top and bottom of each cell

Tags: html, css

I have table as below:

[image]

1. I would like the space in the top and bottom of each cell to be removed. So that rows are even more closer to each other.
2. Expect for heading (first row), I want row lines to be removed. Column lines should stay intact.

My code so far:

```css
#Heading {
  border: 1px dashed white;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#Data {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px dashed white;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#Table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="Table" cellspacing="0" ; cellpadding="0" ;>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="Heading">Row</th>
      <th id="Heading">Data</th>
      <th id="Heading">Item</th>
      <th id="Heading">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <p>Item Details </p>
    <tr>
      <td id="Data">Row</td>
      <td id="Data">data</td>
      <td id="Data">1</td>
      <td id="Data">100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have an invalid html structure. `<p>` can't be a direct child of `<tbody>`. I would say fix this first before worrying about presentation.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is now relevant to CSS and HTML as a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the changes and letting me know that <p> cant be direct child. I will work on that. Rite now, <p> can be excluded.

Comment: There is a big mistake in your code: an id attribute value can only be present 1 time for the page. This might work in CSS, but in js it will be a problem. This is invalid HTML and google does not like that. Use classes instead

Comment: The code you posted doesn't display any additional space in the cells (Click "run code snippet" in your question to see), so there must be more relevant CSS that you didn't post. Have you tried to use the browsers debugger to check which styles are applied to the cells?

Comment: @RoToRa you are correct! My td height was overwritten by another table . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding-left: 30px;   
  padding-right: 30px;
}

tbody td {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<caption>Item Details</caption>
<table id="Table" cellspacing="0" ; cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="Heading">Row</th>
      <th id="Heading">Data</th>
      <th id="Heading">Item</th>
      <th id="Heading">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="Data">Row</td>
      <td id="Data">data</td>
      <td id="Data">1</td>
      <td id="Data">100</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td id="Data">Row</td>
      <td id="Data">data</td>
      <td id="Data">1</td>
      <td id="Data">100</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td id="Data">Row</td>
      <td id="Data">data</td>
      <td id="Data">1</td>
      <td id="Data">100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly how I wanted in terms of row lines. But the space between rows still remains. I want rows to be  close to each other as possible by removing space between them.

Comment: take a look at updated answer